# IOS ReactorKit cell selection not working properly

Tags: uicollectionview, rx-swift, multipleselection, reactor

I'm building a share feature using `uicollectionView`  and `ReactorKit`

My setup is

PhotoListViewReactor.class

```
class PhotoListViewReactor : Reactor {

    enum Action {
        case shareInit
        case select(photo: Photo)
        case deselect(photo: Photo)
        case shareConfirm
        case shareFinish
    }

    enum Mutation {
        case selectShare(_ photo: Photo)
        case deselectShare(_ photo: Photo)
        case setSharingState(Bool)
        case triggerShareAction
        case shareComplete
    }

    struct State {
        var sharePhotos: [Photo] = []
        var isSharing: Bool = false
        var shareAction: Bool = false
    }

    var initialState = State()

    //    init() { }

    func mutate(action: Action) -> Observable<Mutation> {
        switch action {

        case .select(photo: let photo):
            return Observable.just(Mutation.selectShare(photo)).takeUntil(self.action.filter(isSharingAction))

        case .deselect(photo: let photo):
            return Observable.just(Mutation.deselectShare(photo)).takeUntil(self.action.filter(isSharingAction))

        case .shareInit:
            return Observable.just(Mutation.setSharingState(true))

        case .shareConfirm:
            return Observable.concat([Observable.just(Mutation.triggerShareAction), Observable.just(Mutation.setSharingState(false))])
        case .shareFinish:
            return Observable.concat([Observable.just(Mutation.shareComplete),Observable.just(Mutation.setSharingState(false))])
        }
    }

    func reduce(state: State, mutation: Mutation) -> State {
        switch mutation {

        case let .selectShare(photo):
            var newState = state
            newState.sharePhotos.append(photo)
            return newState

        case let .deselectShare(photo):
            var newState = state
            newState.sharePhotos.removeAll(where: { $0.id == photo.id })
            return newState

        case let .setSharingState(isSharing):
            var newState = state
            newState.isSharing = isSharing
            return newState

        case .triggerShareAction:
            var newState = state
            newState.shareAction = true
            return newState

        case .shareComplete:
            var newState = state
            newState.shareAction = false
            newState.isSharing = false
            newState.sharePhotos = []
            return newState

        }
    }

    private func isSharingAction(_ action: Action) -> Bool {
        if case .shareInit = action {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

}
```

and inside `PhotoListViewController`

```
    self.collectionView.rx.modelSelected(Photo.self).share()
        .filter(if: reactor.state.map{$0.isSharing})
        .map {Reactor.Action.select(photo: $0)}
        .bind(to: reactor.action)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)


    self.collectionView.rx.modelDeselected(Photo.self).share()
        .filter(if: reactor.state.map{$0.isSharing})
        .map {Reactor.Action.deselect(photo: $0)}
        .bind(to: reactor.action)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

To be clear my filterIf Operator:

```
extension ObservableType {

    /**
     Filters the source observable sequence using a trigger observable sequence producing Bool values.
     Elements only go through the filter when the trigger has not completed and its last element was true. If either source or trigger error's, then the source errors.
     - parameter trigger: Triggering event sequence.
     - returns: Filtered observable sequence.
     */
    func filter(if trigger: Observable<Bool>) -> Observable<E> {
        return self.withLatestFrom(trigger) { ($0, $1) }
            .filter { $0.1 }
            .map { $0.0 }
    }
}
```

My problem is the selection and deselection does not work properly (once select, user can not deselect the cell by click again). I have enable multisection in uicollectionview.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use with `UICollectionView`'s `selectItem(at:animated:scrollPosition:)` and `deselectItem(at:animated:)` API. `rx.modelDeselect` won't emit any value until select an index path using `selectItem(at:animated:scrollPosition:)`.

Comment: thanks. How can i get the item? using Zip of two methods? or separately?

Comment: Do you have any example that can make select and deselect work with uicollectionview? (add item from action to mutation...)

Comment: Hi. I have tried a few way but none success with cell selection map to Action